# MKL Rectangular Matrix inplace transpose: not using multiple cores?

Tags: c++, c, intel, blas, intel-mkl

I want an in place memory transpose of very large matrix. I am using mkl_simatcopy. But I am observing some performance issue while transposing inplace. I am currently using Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7-8867 v4 @ 2.40GHz having 72 physical cores and RedHat OS.

My observation is that, when I perform transpose  operation, only single core is used and it is not using all cores. I have tried all environment variables like `MK_NUM_THREADS`, `MKL_DYNAMIC="FALSE"` etc.  My compilation script is as follows :

```
gcc  -std=c99    -m64 -I $MKLROOT/include transpose.c  
${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_scalapack_ilp64.a -Wl,--start-group 
${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_cdft_core.a 
${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.a 
${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_tbb_thread.a 
${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a 
${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_blacs_openmpi_ilp64.a -Wl,--end-group  -lstdc++ -lpthread -lm -ldl -o transpose.out
```

Timings obtained are as follows

Sno.    Rows    Cols    Time(in sec)

1      16384   8192     16

2      16384   32768    68

3      32768   65536    233

Data Type is float. Please let me know , if there is an efficient way to transpose inplace or how can we port it to multiple cores.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   unsigned long noOfScan = atol(argv[1]);

   unsigned long noOfPix = atol(argv[2]);

   size_t nEle = noOfScan * noOfPix;

   float *data = (float *)calloc(nEle, sizeof(float));
   initalizeData(data, noOfScan, noOfPix);
   //printdata(data,noOfScan,noOfPix);
   //writeDataFile((char *)data,"BeforeTranspose.img",nEle*sizeof(float));
   printf("After transpose \n\n");
   long nt = mkl_get_max_threads();
   printf("No Of threads are = %d \n", nt);
   //mkl_set_num_threads_local(nt);
   //mkl_set_num_threads(nt);
   double time1 = cpuSecond();
   mkl_simatcopy('R', 'T', noOfScan, noOfPix, 1, data, noOfPix, noOfScan);
   printf("Time elapsed is %lf \n", cpuSecond() - time1);
   memset(data, 0, nEle * sizeof(float));
   free(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/809537) from Intel's forum: `mkl_simatcopy` doesn't support multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this routine is not threaded. In the case, if you really need to have this routine threaded, please submit the feature requests to the intel online service center - https://supporttickets.intel.com/